# Places in India where no vehicles are allowed

Tags: india, health, mumbai

I recently went to Matheran ... a great hill station a few kilometers in the outskirts of Mumbai where no vehicles are allowed , just travelling on foot or by horses or people pulling by hand .

I need to know whether there are any such other places in India to visit where no vehicles are allowed or people do not use it . Just rich nature .

Comment: Matheran is apparently the only automobile-free hill station in Asia. You'll probably have to look at other destinations, such as reserved forests, protected forests and national parks.

Answer (score 8):

The **Taj Mahal** may qualify as one such place. Due to its marbled construction, it is quite susceptible to pollution and hence it is inaccessible by pollution emitting vehicles in what I believe is approximately a 2 mile radius.

The only other vehicles which are allowed in the area are human powered and battery operated *Rickshaws* which must of course stop when entering the complex after which it can only be accessed on foot.

Comment: Tal Mahal or you meant Taj ??

Comment: @DumbCoder They are the same. The word "mahal" essentially means palace.

Comment: I meant Tal or Taj ?

Comment: Haha. Autocorrect sorry!